# Refresh grid view only with in 5 seconds in Pop up

Tags: asp.net

I have a popup on site master page. On this pop up only a gridview is showing. When the popup opens I want to refresh grid only with in 5 seconds and when it closed then stop refreshing.

I used asp Timer, on tick event binding grid with in 5 seconds but it is refreshing the whole page.

Note : Only grid I want to refresh not the whole page.

Comment: what kind of popup you have ? a popup window or a div popup ??

Comment: Use it within a Ajax Update Panel. Read more : **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx**

Comment: A div pop up, In that pop up I am using a user control (which is having a gridview only)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the grid with ajax panel along with time control and make its mode `conditional`.

If you have ajax panel wrapping whole page content then it will refresh whole page. The default mode of update panel is `always` which cause whole page refresh. Mode about update panel [**modes**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode.aspx)

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
```